# Como obtener los valores de la vista al controlador MVC - RAZOR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-6

actualmente tengo este codigo en una vista, y quiero obtener todos los valores para pasarlos al controlador y crearlos en la base de datos

Tengo 2 modelos Materias:

```
namespace CalculaNotas.Models
public class Materias
{

    public int materiasId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(length: 5, ErrorMessage = "El nombre debe contener al menos 5 caracteres")]
    [MaxLength(length: 20, ErrorMessage = "El nombre debe contener maximo 2 caracteres")]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string nombre { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Calificaciones> calificaciones { get; set; }

}
```

Calificaciones:

```
public class Calificaciones
{

    const double MIN_VALUE = 0.0;
    const double MAX_VALUE = 5.0;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int materiasId { get; set; }
    public virtual Materias materia { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nota 1")]
    [Range(minimum: MIN_VALUE, maximum: MAX_VALUE, ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar un numero entre 0.0  y 5.0")]
    public Double nota1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nota 2")]
    [Range(minimum: MIN_VALUE, maximum: MAX_VALUE, ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar un numero entre 0.0  y 5.0")]
    public Double nota2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nota 3")]
    [Range(minimum: MIN_VALUE, maximum: MAX_VALUE, ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar un numero entre 0.0  y 5.0")]
    public Double nota3 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Resultado")]
    public Double resultado { get; set; }


}
```

Y este es el codigo que tengo el la vista para que dinamicamente me muestre las materias almacenadas en la bd y me cree los campos para las calificaciones

```
 @model  CalculaNotas.Models.Calificaciones
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Calificaciones</h4>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr >
            <th class="col-md-1"> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.materia) </th>
            <th class="col-md-1" style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nota1)</th>
            <th class="col-md-1" style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nota2)</th>
            <th class="col-md-1" style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nota3)</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var materia in (IEnumerable<CalculaNotas.Models.Materias>)ViewBag.materias)
        {
            <tr >
                <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(model => materia.nombre)</td>
                <td class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nota1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nota1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nota2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nota2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nota3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nota3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
```

[image: Este es el resultado de la vista]

El codigo del contolador es el siguiente

```
   // GET: Calificaciones/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var materias = db.Materias.ToList();
        ViewBag.materias = materias;
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Calificaciones/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,materiasId,nota1,nota2,nota3,resultado")] Calificaciones calificaciones)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Calificaciones.Add(calificaciones);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.materiasId = new SelectList(db.Materias, "materiasId", "nombre", calificaciones.materiasId);
        return View(calificaciones);
    }
```

Lo que quiero hacer es pasar el id de las materias y las calificaciones que ingrese en los campos al controlador para posteriormente almacenarlos en la base de datos

Comment: Quizás quiera aclarar mas su duda. Al mirar el código observo que los valores de la vista son enviados al controlador y recibidos por el metodo Action Post Create, el que tiene (Bind(Include =..).  De hecho son guardados en la BD usando el contexto db en la tabla Calificaciones. Si usted desea tener esos datos para otros propósitos  puede tomarlos justo allí luego del if (ModelState.IsValid)...

Comment: como ves, en la vista genero varias filas dependiendo de la cantidad de registros en las Materias, pero al validar el modelState solo me pasa la primera fila de datos al controlador, y necesito todos para poderlos guardar en la base de datos

Answer (score 1):

Ya que dices que estas empezando. Le sugiero esta solución para que se haga una mejor idea.
En este ejemplo asumo que no existe propiedades para “nota1, nota2, nota3” en el modelo y por eso no lo uso, además que me parece coherente no tener esas propiedades porque podrían variar en numero.

Para resolver lo haría así:

**1. Crearía un nuevo Controller llamado por ejemplo “Notas”:**

```js
public class NotasController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Notas
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Notas()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Notas(int nota1, int nota2, int nota3)
        {
            return View(); 
        }

    }
}
```

**2. Crearía una nueva vista vacía para ese action.**
El método Post seria el encargado de recibir los datos desde la vista.

Así que le agregaría los parámetros que espero recibir desde la vista y que corresponde con los Id de los campos de texto, las notas.

En la vista crearía un formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya que el ActionResult y la vista tienen el mismo nombre lo buscara automáticamente.

Note que los Id de los campos de texto corresponden con los parámetros del método ActionResult “Notas”.

Como podrá notar los valores escritos en el formulario (BeginForm) en la vista son enviados al hacer clic en el boton enviar y recibidos en el controlador tal y como se ve en la ventana de variables locales.

En ese punto ya se podrá hacer la inserción en la bd.

Ojala este ejemplo te oriente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

en el controlador debes recibir un arreglo de calificaciones, no solo un objeto

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Calificaciones[] calificaciones)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Calificaciones.Add(calificaciones);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }


}
```